# mariadb/mysql - How to make a date column with sysdate/curdate?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I want to make a column in my table that has the equivalent functionality as the oracle sysdate variable as the default value. So when a row is inserted (without the date, the current sysdate is used). what is the query to create this table?
Also should I allow nulls for this column, how would that work?

Also, I want to be able to insert a row into this table, such that the functionality occurs. Please provide sample insert query that uses this functionality.

Also, I want to be able to do the same for the DATETIME column type.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty well explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html):

> TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns can be automatically initializated and
>   updated to the current date and time (that is, the current timestamp).

The syntax looks like:

```
create table t (
    . . .,
    createdAt datetime not null default current_timestamp
);
```

If you are giving the column a default value, then you might as well declare it as `NOT NULL`.

You can also do the same thing for updates:

```
    updatedAt datetime not null default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp
```

Comment: @scriptAddict . . . I don't think so.